# Change LastLogonDate property in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing a script to disable old workstation objects (and I have to remake the wheel due to some unique things on my system). I'd like to make some test computer objects with known LastLogonDate to validate my script.

How can I, preferably just with PowerShell, set the LastLogonDate property to what I want it to be? I'd prefer it to be in PowerShell so I can include the necessary changes in order self-test my code when it runs. I am also heavily restricted on what programs can be placed on the network.

I haven't found a pure PowerShell solution, and TechNet indicates that Set-ADComputer doesn't have that functionality. In desperation I've tried running ADSIedit on a domain controller to set LastLogon and LastLogonTimestamp, but get error 0x209a (attribute is owned by the Security Accounts Manager).

Worst case scenario, I can use a previously disabled workstation but that workaround is getting a lot of frowns from my security folks.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

If I can figure out how to get around that "error 0x209a (attribute is owned by the Security Accounts Manager" issue, I think I can use the following PowerShell to set it:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity <ComputerName> -Server <DomainController> | Set-ADObject -DisplayName <ComputerName> -Replace @{LastLogon=<NewTimeStamp>}
```

Where NewTimeStamp is the tick count of the date you want to set.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this value is meant to be modified _at all_. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To make test objects with known values for validating whether the script is working as intended.

Comment: LastLogonDate might not be the attribute you really want to query against, or modify. It does not replicate.

Comment: For anyone coming in looking for this, what you want is to Mock the response on the object. Pester is the tool for PowerShell that allows this. I'm sorry that I don't have code solution for this.
What I ended up doing was creating some dummy accounts and just waiting for them to hit certain ages. This was because my environment was incredibly restrictive and I couldn't use Pester.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify! Both [LastLogon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676823(v=vs.85).aspx) and [LastLogonTimeStamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676824(v=vs.85).aspx) are system-owned attributes and even if you found a way to bypass the restriction, you would most likely break the replication of the object.

There's nothing wrong with disabling and moving old unused computer objects. Your security folks would however hate you if you broke AD by doing unsupported modifications.

`LastLogonDate` is a virtual/calculated property created by the AD-module for easy access to a datetime-converted property of for the `LastLogonTimeStamp`-attribute.

Comment: I'm not saying this was a good thing to do, this was a requirement given to me. Mocking would be a good solution to this, if it had been allowed (it wasn't). I was stuck with a bad project.